# How to appropriately reply to "You're going to hell"?

Tags: christian-living, hell

According to global Christianity, what is the most Christlike way to respond to someone who randomly walks up to you and says, "You're going to hell"?

Comment: I'd probably start by asking "Why do you say that?"

Comment: . . . . .  and, who gave you the authority to say it ?

Comment: Ignoring is always an option.

Comment: Regrettably, this site isn't for discussion or advice, and so will have to be closed as off topic. Please feel free to ask other question, and have a look at the help pages for more information about how to write an on topic question.

Comment: Having said that, there's lots of possible smarta** responses (my favourite would be a cheery "See you there!") but curousdanni is on the right track for Christlike.

Comment: "I would, but I'm not. Because of Jesus"

Comment: Regrettably, the people most likely to walk up to strangers and say "You're going to hell" are people who already think they are Christians.

Comment: My reply is most likely as DJ says: "See you there; I'll save you a spot if I get there first."  My other answer is "Wait, are you telling me that I need to go to Confession?"

Comment: Do not see why this question was closed, when the following one was not: [Is there an appropriate response to “Jesus Loves You”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/74332/25495)

Comment: @KenGraham Because that question was asking about whether there is an "approved" or "accepted" or "normal" cultural response to something, which is answerable. This is asking about how to deal with an aggressive verbal attack, which is entirely different.

Comment: @DJClayworth I do not believe that was remotely stated in any of the editing or in the original post.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there KenGraham. "Jesus loves you" is pretty friendly and this...isn't.

Comment: Well, the world is. That's old news.

Comment: The obvious answer would be *Yes, I know*. (Matthew 7:13-14).

Answer (score 5):

**How to reply to “You're going to hell”?**

***”May God mercy on my soul and yours as well.”*** And remember well that we will both face our Eternal Judge some day!

> **"May God have mercy upon your soul"** or **"may God have mercy on your soul"** is a phrase used within courts in various legal systems by judges pronouncing a sentence of death upon a person found guilty of a crime that requires a death sentence. The phrase originated in beth din courts in the Kingdom of Israel as a way to attribute God as the highest authority in law. The usage of the phrase later spread to England and Wales' legal system and from there to usage throughout the colonies of the British Empire whenever a death sentence was passed.
>
> Depending on where it is used, the phrase has had different emphasis through the years. It was formally intended as a prayer for the soul of the condemned. However, in later times, particularly in the United States, it has only been said as a result of legal tradition where the religious meaning and origin is not founded on belief. - [May God have mercy upon your soul](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_God_have_mercy_upon_your_soul)